# GeoJSON with lower precision

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, dictionary, geojson

I have a geoJSON that I am using to render a globe using D3.

I need to reduce the number of coordinates (make it less precise, more coarse).

Please do not suggest using topoJSON. A link to a geoJSON with fewer coordinates will also be helpful.

```
var projection = d3.geo.orthographic().scale(300);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var countries = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width: 900, height: 900}).append('svg:g')
                    .selectAll('path')
                   .data(world.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append('svg:path')
                           .attr('d', path);
```

fiddle here - > http://jsfiddle.net/8yt9pp3r/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The chart looks nice. What's your question?

Comment: Some of the options in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029434/convert-shp-to-topojson-failing) answer have the ability to reduce the precision of geojson

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all those who took time looking into my question. I found a solution to my question and that is [this](http://www.mapshaper.org/) website.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree with you Alexis, but the link is to a service. The service reduces the precision of the geoJSON.

Comment: Useful link! Thanks. As a hint: the website provides a front end for the following library: https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper which can be used separately as well

Answer (score 2):

There is a JavaScript tool called geojson-precision, available at https://github.com/jczaplew/geojson-precision or via npm.

Their example reads as

```
geojson-precision -p 4 input.json output.json
```

where `-p 4` makes it cut to 4 decimal places.